# Solution to the functional equation $f(z)=(-1)^zf(1-z)$???

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

I was playing around with various functional equations and I created this particular one:
$$f(z)=(-1)^zf(1-z)$$

Where $z$ is a complex number. I was wondering how I would go about finding a solution to this equation if one even exists.

Comment: What is your definition of $(-1)^z$? Is it $\exp(z\pi i)$, $\exp(-z\pi i)$, or something else?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it is $e^{i \pi z}$

Comment: @Arthur yup. just figured that out

Comment: $f(z)=0$ seems like a (trivial) solution, answering whether a solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$f(z)=(-1)^zf(1-z)$$

If we replace $z$ with $1-z$ we get $$f(1-z)=(-1)^{1-z}f(z)$$ and thus

$$f(z) = (-1)^z(-1)^{1-z}f(z) = (-1)^1f(z)$$

so $f(z)=0$ for all $z$.